# Connecting to Sybase From Scala

Tags: database, scala, sap-ase

I am writing a web application which requires connecting to Sybase ASE from Scala code.I have JDBC and ScalikeJDBC in my mind.Which is the best driver for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure which Sybase JDBC driver is the best, ScalikeJDBC works with any JDBC drivers that correctly implement JDBC specification.